# Why wont the parent change the height to wrap the text view?

Tags: android, xml

I am baffled as to why this parent relative layout with id main_layout* will not adjust its height for the view with id is_admin.

Here is the code. Put in to an xml file and preview in Android Studio to see the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/user_item_rellayout_paddingrightleft"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/user_item_rellayout_paddingrightleft"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/user_container">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_above="@+id/profile_image_layout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/user_item_isadmin_marginbottom"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:id="@+id/is_admin"
            android:text="ADMIN"
            android:textSize="@dimen/user_item_isadmin_size"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/profile_image_layout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:src="@color/delim_grey"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/profile_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                />
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/sent_icon"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/sent_tick"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_green"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
            />
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_white"
                >
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <TextView
            fontPath="font/AvenirNext-Medium-06.ttf"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_item_username_margintop"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image_layout"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:text="TOTO"
            android:textSize="11dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/user_item_fullname_margintop"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textSize="8dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/username"
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:text="toto titi"
            android:textColor="@color/hintGrey"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you've set the property `android:layout_above="@+id/profile_image_layout"` to the view with id `android:id="@+id/is_admin"` and `profile_image_layout` is at the top of the view.

It's fine when you set it to `android:layout_below="@id/fullname"`

Comment: Okay so if I move its position in the xml above the profile_image id it still has the same result. There is nothing in the profile_image_layout that indicates that it would somehow push the is_admin layout somewhere else. Unless I have misunderstood your answer?

Comment: Sorry, bad answer. Edited